# Execute a function on Mouseover for nested divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am showing an example code:

```
<div onmouseover="function1(e)">
   SomeContent 1
   <div onmouseover="function2(e)"> SomeContent 2</div>
</div>
```

Here both `function1()` and `function2()` are being executed when mouseover is on inner div. If the mouse is on inner div it should only execute `function2()`.
I have even tried using `e.stopPropagation()` too.

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using JQuery i suggest to use **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** :

> **Description:** Attach an event handler function for one or more events to the selected elements.

Instead of inline event handlers that considered as a bad practice e.g :

```js
$('#content_1').on('mouseover' , function(e){
    $('#console').text('function 1');
});

$('#content_2').on('mouseover' , function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    $('#console').text('function2');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="content_1">
   SomeContent 1
   <div id="content_2"> SomeContent 2</div>
</div>

<br>
<span id='console'></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

stopPropagation() is working for me. Maybe you weren't using it right?

Below snippet also works for `.on('mouseenter',..`

```js
$('div').hover(function(e) {
  if ($(e.target).is('div.parent')) {
    console.log('parent');
    e.stopPropagation();
  } else if ($(e.target).is('div.child')) {
    console.log('child');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  SomeContent 1
  <div class="child">SomeContent 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. Does this help? "window.event" is the object which is available for onclick, not "window.e".

```js
var function1 = function(){
  console.log("func1"); 

}

var function2 = function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  console.log("func2"); 

}
```

```html
<div onmouseover="function1(event)" style="padding:30px;background:red;">
   SomeContent 1
   <div onmouseover="function2(event)" style="background:yellow"> SomeContent 2</div>
</div>
```